# Multiple bounding boxes after training upto 50k+ steps in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter, object-detection

I have tried to train a model which can detect an apple.I have trained it on batch size 1 with more than 50k steps.I implemented it by following sentdex tutorials .When I test in jupiter,it gives multiple bounding boxes + it also detects chair as an apple.What is the solution of this problem.below is the screenshot of what is going on

[Picture 1 Apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmA3R.png)

[Picture 2 Apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abPQP.png)

[Picture 3 Apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YTRY.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to help you as we don't know anything about the dataset (domain, size of images, etc), the network architecture (ssd mobilenet? faster rcnn inception?), the configuration of your training, etc. Add more info.

Comment: i am using ssd mobilenet

Comment: In my knowledge, SSD Mobilenet need more steps in the training phase. You don't say anything about the dataset, configuration file, batch size etc.. the only think that you can do is to try to train it for +200k steps and try to see the outcome again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add some negative samples in your train dataset.